# Javascript while does not work in console

Tags: javascript, while-loop, console, timestamp, javascript-debugger

Good morning, when I want to run this code in a console, the browser blocks me (**Error: A web page is slowing down your browser**). 
I'm not sure how to avoid this error.

```
var term = Date.now();
var term = term + 30000; // + 30 sec

while (1) {

    var now = Date.now();

    if(now > term) {

        alert("Now");
        break; // when is actual time (now) bigger than term, I will stop the script
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'blocks' you? do you get an error? Does nothing happen?

Comment: StackOverflow, that's what you're doing with your infinite loop

Comment: What is the purpose? wait 30 seconds and execute some code?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky it isn't a stackoverflow, it will alert now and break the loop after 30 seconds have passed

Comment: if you want only wait for specific time to perform then use setTimeout(function(){
...........
}, 30000)

Comment: @Katie.Sun it runs as many times as it can, I logged 169 309 runs for 30s. definitely capable of shutting down the browser on some systems.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky ok but it certainly isn't infinite

Comment: Katie.Sun you are right, certainly not, it might outlive your browser though :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it in a non-blocking form. Use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(()=> {
  alert("Now");
}, 30000);
```

If you want to wait for specific timestamp just setTimeout X seconds, doing the operation:

```
var miliseconds_to_wait = timestamp - Date.now();

setTimeout(()=>{
  alert("Now");
}, miliseconds_to_wait);
```

Comment: And what if I will want to wait for a specific timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

setInterval to repeat some task after specific time.

```
setInterval(()=> alert("Now"), 1000);
```

setTimeout wait for specific time.

```
setTimeout(()=> {
      alert("Now");
    }, 30000);
```

Comment: And what if I will want to wait for a specific timestamp?

Comment: then use setTimeout